# Not able to open Firefox using geckodriver in mac OS

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to open the firefox browser in mac machine.
As I am using latest selenium jar file, so for opening the Firefox browser, I am using geckodriver but not able to launch the browser.

Below are the code which I am using for opening the browser using geckodriver:

```
public class Apache_POI_TC {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[]arg) throws Exception{

        //This is to open the Excel file. Excel path, file name and the sheet name are parameters to this method
        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData+ Constant.File_TestData, "Sheet1");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/ileadsynapse/Desktop/CT/geckodriver");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
        SignIn_Action.Execution(driver);
        System.out.println("Login successfully.");
        Home_Page.lnk_LogOut(driver).click();
        driver.quit();

        //This is to send the PASS value to the Excel sheet in the result column.
        ExcelUtils.setCellData("Pass", 1, 3);
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.newLogger(LogAdapter.java:34)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.newLogger(LogAdapter.java:30)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.<init>(AbstractVerifier.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.<init>(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:44)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.<clinit>(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:46)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:224)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
    at automationFramework.Apache_POI_TC.main(Apache_POI_TC.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve the problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you using latest versions of firefox and geckodriver??

Comment: @Ranjith's Yes, Firefox version: 54.0.1 (64-bit) and Selenium version: 3.4.0.

Comment: what about geckodriver??

Comment: @Ranjith's geckodriver version- v0.17.0-macos.tr.gz

Comment: what is the error/exception you are getting.

Comment: @GaurangShah I have just added the error which I am getting at the time of running. Please help to resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue for not opening the Firefox browser using geckodriver in mac machine get resolved after configuring the below jars in build path:

```
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.6.jar
xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
```